# Api is returning media data in response.body in Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am using api in flutter that is returning media data so how to handle this.

[ScreenShot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFLQE.png)

[Post Man screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDWpR.png)

Thanks in advance for your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

Save your response to temp file or application document directory and add Image.file widget to your project to show this downloaded file. to save file you can use [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package.

```
          if(response.statusCode == 200) {
            var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
            filePath = '$dir/$fileName';
            file = File(filePath);
            await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
          }
          else
            filePath = 'Error code: '+response.statusCode.toString();
        }
```

also check this stackoverflow [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197053/download-file-from-url-save-to-phones-storage).