# how to load file from online in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm able to load file from my code. But the problem is, how to load the file from online server which is from this link- https://freevpn.gg/c/59.139.187.41/udp

My current code is-

var contennt=await rootBundle.loadString('assets/vpnconfig.ovpn');

Comment: Try this option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54197191/2831595

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62476108/how-to-load-and-present-a-pdf-file-from-the-web-in-flutter
**Try this**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use flutter cache manager to download the file and then read it. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager

```
String url = 'your_link';
final file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);
var content = await file.readAsString();
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     dependencies:
>   flutter_filereader: ^2.2.0
> ```

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'dart:io';
    
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_filereader_example/file.dart';
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        Permission.storage.request();
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: HomePage(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      String taskId;
    
      Map<String, String> iosfiles = {
        "docx": "assets/files/docx.docx", // IOS test
        "doc": "assets/files/doc.doc", // IOS test
        "xlsx": "assets/files/xlsx.xlsx", // IOS test
        "xls": "assets/files/xls.xls", // IOS test
        "pptx": "assets/files/pptx.pptx", // IOS test
        "ppt": "assets/files/ppt.ppt", // IOS test
        "pdf": "assets/files/pdf.pdf", // IOS test
        "txt": "assets/files/txt.txt", // IOS test
        "jpg": "assets/files/jpg.jpg", //
        "jpeg": "assets/files/jpeg1.jpeg", //
        "png": "assets/files/png.png", //
      };
    
      Map<String, String> androidfiles = {
        "docx": "assets/files/docx.docx", // android test
        "doc": "assets/files/doc.doc", // android test
        "xlsx": "assets/files/xlsx.xlsx", // android test
        "xls": "assets/files/xls.xls", // android test
        "pptx": "assets/files/pptx.pptx", // android test
        "ppt": "assets/files/ppt.ppt", // android test
        "pdf": "assets/files/pdf.pdf", // android test
        "txt": "assets/files/txt.txt" // android test
      };
    
      Map<String, String> files;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          files = androidfiles;
        } else {
          files = iosfiles;
        }
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('File Reader'),
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
              return item(files.keys.elementAt(index), files.values.elementAt(index));
            },
            itemCount: files.length,
          ),
        );
      }
    
      item(String type, String path) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            onTap(type, path);
          },
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 50,
            margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(bottom: 5),
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                type,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      onTap(String type, String assetPath) async {
        String localPath = await fileLocalName(type, assetPath);
        if (!await File(localPath).exists()) {
          if (!await asset2Local(type, assetPath)) {
            return;
          }
        }
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) {
          return FileReaderPage(
            filePath: localPath,
          );
        }));
      }
    
      fileLocalName(String type, String assetPath) async {
        String dic = await _localSavedDir() + "/filereader/files/";
        return dic + base64.encode(utf8.encode(assetPath)) + "." + type;
      }
    
      fileExists(String type, String assetPath) async {
        String fileName = await fileLocalName(type, assetPath);
        if (await File(fileName).exists()) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    
      asset2Local(String type, String assetPath) async {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          if (!await Permission.storage.isGranted) {
            debugPrint("没有存储权限");
            return false;
          }
        }
    
        File file = File(await fileLocalName(type, assetPath));
        if (await fileExists(type, assetPath)) {
          await file.delete();
        }
        await file.create(recursive: true);
        //await file.create();
        debugPrint("文件路径->" + file.path);
        ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load(assetPath);
        await file.writeAsBytes(bd.buffer.asUint8List(), flush: true);
        return true;
      }
    
      _localSavedDir() async {
        Directory dic;
        if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
          dic = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
        } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
          dic = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        }
        return dic.path;
      }
    }
```