# Cannot download file from url?

Tags: flutter

I just want to download a file from a url using flutter_downloader package, my code is very simple:

```
  String url =  await _databaseService.getContractDownloadUrl();
  await DownloadHelper.download(url);
```

The file is an image from wikipedia, just for test : https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/GatesofArctic.jpg

When i click on my button a notification with "started" compare, but then the app crash and it fails. This is my console:

```
W/WM-WorkSpec(17674): Backoff delay duration less than minimum value
D/DownloadWorker(17674): DownloadWorker{url=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/GatesofArctic.jpg,filename=null,savedDir=/sdcard/download/,header=,isResume=false
D/DownloadWorker(17674): Update notification: {notificationId: 10, title: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/GatesofArctic.jpg, status: 2, progress: 0}
D/DownloadWorker(17674): Open connection to https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/GatesofArctic.jpg
I/System.out(17674): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(17674): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/DownloadWorker(17674): Content-Type = image/jpeg
D/DownloadWorker(17674): Content-Length = 821472
D/DownloadWorker(17674): Charset = null
D/DownloadWorker(17674): Content-Disposition = null
D/DownloadWorker(17674): fileName = GatesofArctic.jpg
D/DownloadWorker(17674): Update too frequently!!!!, but it is the final update, we should sleep a second to ensure the update call can be processed
I/flutter (17674): Fatal: could not find callback
F/flutter (17674): [FATAL:flutter/fml/message_loop.cc(78)] Check failed: loop != nullptr. MessageLoop::EnsureInitializedForCurrentThread was not called on this thread prior to message loop use.
F/libc    (17674): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 18686 (1.raster), pid 17674 (ia.tiParcheggio)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/beyond1lteeea/beyond1:11/RP1A.200720.012/G973FXXU9FUBD:user/release-keys'
Revision: '26'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2021-05-17 17:41:59+0200
pid: 17674, tid: 18686, name: 1.raster  >>> com.resmedia.tiParcheggio <<<
uid: 10368
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/fml/message_loop.cc(78)] Check failed: loop != nullptr. MessageLoop::EnsureInitializedForCurrentThread was not called on this thread prior to message loop use.
'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000048fe  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007c1d830570
    x4  0000007f973c1000  x5  0000007f973c1000  x6  0000007f973c1000  x7  0000000005d82e92
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  0000007f93e769e8  x10 ffffff80fffffbdf  x11 0000000000000001
    x12 0000007c1d82f380  x13 00000000000000b0  x14 0000000000000000  x15 0000263e909d145c
    x16 0000007f93f0fc80  x17 0000007f93ef18b0  x18 0000007c0c0a2000  x19 00000000000000ac
    x20 000000000000450a  x21 00000000000000b2  x22 00000000000048fe  x23 00000000ffffffff
    x24 0000007d3f92f9e8  x25 0000007c1d831000  x26 0000000000000001  x27 000000000000005d
    x28 0000000000000001  x29 0000007c1d8305f0
    lr  0000007f93ea49cc  sp  0000007c1d830550  pc  0000007f93ea49fc  pst 0000000000000000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000004e9fc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+180) (BuildId: 60535ec972fea6eddd93daf23db05208)
      #01 pc 00000000012ef1b8  /data/app/~~yKLi-g8H3pUVlRavTcZiwA==/com.resmedia.tiParcheggio-81kQOxG6670OkYk5KC0evQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 3beb04d15ca0dce5daadd727726b8965ef57468d)
      #02 pc 00000000013127cc  /data/app/~~yKLi-g8H3pUVlRavTcZiwA==/com.resmedia.tiParcheggio-81kQOxG6670OkYk5KC0evQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 3beb04d15ca0dce5daadd727726b8965ef57468d)
      #03 pc 0000000001312eec  /data/app/~~yKLi-g8H3pUVlRavTcZiwA==/com.resmedia.tiParcheggio-81kQOxG6670OkYk5KC0evQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 3beb04d15ca0dce5daadd727726b8965ef57468d)
      #04 pc 0000000001315810  /data/app/~~yKLi-g8H3pUVlRavTcZiwA==/com.resmedia.tiParcheggio-81kQOxG6670OkYk5KC0evQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 3beb04d15ca0dce5daadd727726b8965ef57468d)
      #05 pc 0000000001315848  /data/app/~~yKLi-g8H3pUVlRavTcZiwA==/com.resmedia.tiParcheggio-81kQOxG6670OkYk5KC0evQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 3beb04d15ca0dce5daadd727726b8965ef57468d)
      #06 pc 00000000013481c8  /data/app/~~yKLi-g8H3pUVlRavTcZiwA==/com.resmedia.tiParcheggio-81kQOxG6670OkYk5KC0evQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 3beb04d15ca0dce5daadd727726b8965ef57468d)
      #07 pc 0000000001352bb4  /data/app/~~yKLi-g8H3pUVlRavTcZiwA==/com.resmedia.tiParcheggio-81kQOxG6670OkYk5KC0evQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 3beb04d15ca0dce5daadd727726b8965ef57468d)
      #08 pc 0000000001313298  /data/app/~~yKLi-g8H3pUVlRavTcZiwA==/com.resmedia.tiParcheggio-81kQOxG6670OkYk5KC0evQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 3beb04d15ca0dce5daadd727726b8965ef57468d)
      #09 pc 00000000013183d0  /data/app/~~yKLi-g8H3pUVlRavTcZiwA==/com.resmedia.tiParcheggio-81kQOxG6670OkYk5KC0evQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 3beb04d15ca0dce5daadd727726b8965ef57468d)
      #10 pc 000000000001a064  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+916) (BuildId: f7e62c203d9645802caa9325d785d7c9)
      #11 pc 0000000000019c68  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+112) (BuildId: f7e62c203d9645802caa9325d785d7c9)
      #12 pc 0000000000012d3c  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+100) (BuildId: 24b6586fe44ab8ec8b04f4f5f65be25d)
      #13 pc 0000000001318358  /data/app/~~yKLi-g8H3pUVlRavTcZiwA==/com.resmedia.tiParcheggio-81kQOxG6670OkYk5KC0evQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 3beb04d15ca0dce5daadd727726b8965ef57468d)
      #14 pc 00000000013131e0  /data/app/~~yKLi-g8H3pUVlRavTcZiwA==/com.resmedia.tiParcheggio-81kQOxG6670OkYk5KC0evQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 3beb04d15ca0dce5daadd727726b8965ef57468d)
      #15 pc 000000000131613c  /data/app/~~yKLi-g8H3pUVlRavTcZiwA==/com.resmedia.tiParcheggio-81kQOxG6670OkYk5KC0evQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 3beb04d15ca0dce5daadd727726b8965ef57468d)
      #16 pc 00000000000b10e8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64) (BuildId: 60535ec972fea6eddd93daf23db05208)
      #17 pc 0000000000050a58  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 60535ec972fea6eddd93daf23db05208)
Lost connection to device.
```

In my Manifest I have this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and this (with or without it doesn't work anyway):

```
 <provider
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

I'm using Flutter 2.0.6. Am i doing something wrong? Do you have any alternatives?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason for not using the normal Http modules of `dart:io` ?

Comment: Try doing `flutter clean`, then `flutter pub get`, then running the app again. If it still doesn't work, it may be a package bug, as reported [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=MessageLoop%3A%3AEnsureInitializedForCurrentThread+was+not+called+on+this+thread+prior+to+message+loop+use).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's related to this post?

[Download file from url, save to phones storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197053/download-file-from-url-save-to-phones-storage)

Here is one of the useful code snippet from above link

```
final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: 'your download link',
  savedDir: 'the path of directory where you want to save downloaded files',
  showNotification: true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
  openFileFromNotification: true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
);
```