# How to receive an application/pdf stream?

Tags: flutter, stream

I've worked a bit with streams with Firestore but never with restful. Our flutter app needs to receive an application/pdf stream. When the stream is done, I need to store it in local storage (iOS/Android).

What does that look like? Would I use a SteamBuilder, like what I used with Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're downloading from a REST Api you would need to call a HTTP get request, then save the file to local storage. You can this library, [Flutter donwloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) to download the file and save it directly to the phone's storage. This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197053/download-file-from-url-save-to-phones-storage) shows how to download PDF's using the library. If you're feeling adventurous, then you can use [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) to handle the HTTP call then use [local storage](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage) to save the file to your phone.