# How to download video from tiktok url by flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, video, download, tiktok

I would like to download video from tiktok url by flutter.
I was able to extract only video url from tiktok video url.
Like this
https://v16-webapp.tiktok.com/16301adb3bdaee90952c0a29ba9aa269/6280a48d/video/tos/alisg/tos-alisg-pve-0037/4513bbabd77948d0ad68ea9154d3c580/?a=1988&br=700&bt=350&cd=0%7C0%7C1%7C0&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&ft=eXd.6HVJMyq8Zjhdlwe2NZZK2l7Gb&l=202205150054570102440750600FBBD34F&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&qs=0&rc=M2V2ZjQ6ZnZ3PDMzODgzNEApMzdlOWQ3OTtkNzQ7ZTxkZmdzbTBocjRvYHNgLS1kLy1zczI2YDVeNWFgMWIyLmJjYTI6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=

However, the last of this url is not ".mp4" and I can find only how to download video from ".mp4 link" on the web.
Please teach me how to download video from "not mp4" video link to my iphone by flutter!

Comment: I don't use Flutter but your link's data **is already an MP4**. Does Flutter allow a coder to set an output filename before saving? Does your _"downloading"_ mean play video inside Flutter or does it mean save video file to a device's storage?

Comment: Thank you for your replying. 
First question's answer is "I do not know".
Second one is "Latter".
If you want to save video file to a device's storage by flutter, you need to use video link whose last is ".mp4" because you cannot save video link whose last is not ".mp4".

Comment: This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64661261/2057709) seems to suggest reading the video into a bytes Array then write those bytes as a file in storage. You create a **File** object with your preferred filename (_eg:_ in code the `$filename` becomes _"test.mp4"_).

Answer (score 0):

"This Answer seems to suggest reading the video into a bytes Array then write those bytes as a file in storage. You create a File object with your preferred filename (eg: in code the $filename becomes "test.mp4"). –
VC.One
May 15 at 12:26"

This is an Answer!!
Thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can do inspect element and then go to network tab and then go to media tab. After that click on the video on tiktok website whose mp4 you want, and it will appear in the media tab . You can go to that url which will be a cdn and download it from there.