# Flutter how to download file in device from api response type blob object

Tags: flutter, postman, blob

Flutter how to download file in device from api response type blob object

Recommend flutter library....?

Please...

Postman results are attached below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttxYD.png)

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download file from url, save to phones storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197053/download-file-from-url-save-to-phones-storage)